# Stair lighting going down to lake

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I purchased a home 25 years old on a lake bluff.  Some of the stair way light fixtures going down to the lake need replaced (3 of the 5).  I couldn't get a picture attached.  There is a metal housing that contains the light which shines down and an attached metal box.  I'm guessing the box hardware converts the voltage down if the lights are lower voltage.  The stairway is wired with 115V.  Are these something that are commonly available?

Comment: You need to stop guessing 25 years ago there would have been 120v or 12v lighting. LED’s we’re not really a thing yet. 
Using a volt meter check the voltage. Just because it goes close to the water doesn’t require low voltage. I have wired docks with 120v lights and they are only inches above the water line in some cases.

Comment: yes, low-voltage outdoor lighting is a huge product category with options almost guaranteed to swap out with or update your existing setup. I would go 12v LED-based. You might just have burnt-out halogens (they only last 1000 hours), in which case you can simply swap in some LED retrofit bulbs in all the fixtures, working or not.

Comment: You can [edit] your post then click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box to paste in your image, or, if you're on a PC/Mac, just drag/drop the image into the edit box. If you're still struggling, upload the pics to imgur, paste a link into the post and someone will embed them for you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the metal box hardware please?